# Python / PIP on Mac hosed

Tags: python, macos, pip

I think the system install of Python is okay. I can open up the python shell from bash without trouble. But PIP is no longer. I am also trying to run Ansible but that just quit working.

What I was doing was trying to fix issues with modules installing but not able to be imported. I uninstalled then re-installed and that was fixing most of my issues, then everything just came crashing down.

Issue 1: PIP gone.
PIP show 'command not found'. So maybe a symlink is gone? I try to re-install via https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/ and get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

When trying to use easy_install I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==18.5', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/Users/farroar/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 484, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/farroar/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2725, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/farroar/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2343, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Users/farroar/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2349, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 46, in <module>
    from setuptools.archive_util import unpack_archive
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/archive_util.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import ensure_directory, ContextualZipFile
ImportError: cannot import name ContextualZipFile
```

which -a python gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

I installed python with brew and reinstalled but receive an error during the process:

```
error: could not delete '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py': Permission denied
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall python@2`
```

when I try to run ansible WITHOUT assuming root I get a weird error:

```
.....
", line 18, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.name import Name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509/name.py", line 28, in <module>
    _ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = dict((i.value, i) for i in _ASN1Type)
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

I'm hoping for some direction here. Everything was working fine until I encountered a module that wouldn't load. Chased that down into a hole.

Comment: I ended up deleting all of the brew installed Python packages. This seemed to rectify the issue. Now everything is back to normal. Had to re-install all of the packages that I needed for Ansible and other items.

Answer (score 0):

1. RUN: `which pip`
2. Did you installed Python using `brew`. If you did, `brew doctor` to see if there's an unlinked file.
3. Try to run your application using `python2` directly.

Comment: which pip results in nothing. I did install using brew and doctor shows that everything is good " ready to brew".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it seems that if you bang on something long enough, it just gives in. I uninstalled (again) the brew python installation. After that, I was able to install pip. It's all very strange. Something with brew is messing everything up.

Do I really even NEED to use brew for python? I'm guessing only if I needed to use a version other than 2.7.10, correct?

Comment: If you use Anaconda you can easily install python2.7 and python3.6. You can then go to https://www.python.org/downloads/ and download aversion you want. YHou can download any version you want from python.org.  Anaconda just make it simple to set up your virtual environments...